# Characters are scrambled when using std::cerr

Tags: c++, unicode, character, ascii

I am currently working on a project for school, and no matter what I do to my input file or implementation I can not get it to work.

The code works fine in Visual Studios 2017, but now I'm in Linux environment using g++.

**code:**

getLineFromTextFile(std::string textOrCin):

```
std::string getLineFromTextFile(std::string textOrCin) {
std::string currentLine;

if (textOrCin == "text") {
    if (!inputStream.eof()) {
        std::getline(inputStream, currentLine);
        //as long as currentLine's first two digits are "//..."
        while ((currentLine[0] == '/' && currentLine[1] == '/') || currentLine == "") {
            std::getline(inputStream, currentLine);
        }
        std::cout << currentLine << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(400));
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "[global::getLineFromTextFile]: Critcal Error; End of file found, can't load anymore!\n";
        std::cerr << "exiting...";
        throw;
    }
}
else if (textOrCin == "cin") {
    std::cin >> currentLine;
}
else {
    std::cerr << "[global::getLineFromTextFile]: Critcal Error; Invalid 'textOrCin' input.\n";
    std::cerr << "exiting...";
    throw;
}
return currentLine;
}
```

Function Implementation:

```
void ZoinkersEngine::displayMainMenu(User& currentUser, std::string textOrCin) {
std::string option = "";
if (currentUser.getRole() == "admin") {
    do {
        std::cout << std::string(40, '\n');
        std::cout << "Successfully logged in...\n\n\n";
        std::cout << "Main Menu:\n";
        std::cout << "[0] Order Plan\n";
        std::cout << "[1] Generate Plan\n";
        std::cout << "[2] Manage Profile\n";
        std::cout << "[3] Manage Exhibits\n";
        std::cout << "[4] Manage Animals\n";
        std::cout << "[5] Manage Users\n";
        std::cout << "[6] Search Animal/Exhibit by Name\n";
        std::cout << "[7] Record Favorability\n";
        std::cout << "[8] Log Animal/Exhibit Care\n";
        std::cout << "[9] Add or Remove an Exhibit\n";
        std::cout << "[10] Add or Remove an Animal\n";
        std::cout << "[Cancel] To exit\n\n";

        std::cout << "Please input number of selected option: ";
        // std::cin >> option;
        option = getLineFromTextFile(textOrCin);

        //DEBUG START
        std::cerr << "Option: [" << option "].\n";
        std::cerr << "Option.size(): [" << option.size() "].\n";
        //DEBUG END


        if (option == "0") {
            currentUser.calculateExhibitFav(zoinkersDirectory);
            currentUser.orderPlan(zoinkersDirectory, textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "1") {
            currentUser.calculateExhibitFav(zoinkersDirectory);
            currentUser.generatePlan(zoinkersDirectory, textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "2") {
            currentUser.manageProfile(zoinkersDirectory, textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "3") {
            zoinkersDirectory.manageExhibit(currentUser.getUsername(), textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "4") {
            zoinkersDirectory.manageAnimal(currentUser.getUsername(), textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "5") {
            zoinkersDirectory.manageUsers(currentUser.getUsername(), textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "6") {
            zoinkersDirectory.searchAnimalExhibit(textOrCin, currentUser);
        }
        else if (option == "7") {
            currentUser.favorabilityUI(zoinkersDirectory, textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "8") {
            currentUser.logExhibitCare(textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "9") {
            zoinkersDirectory.addRemoveExhibit(currentUser.getUsername(), textOrCin);
        }
        else if (option == "10") {
            zoinkersDirectory.addRemoveAnimal(currentUser.getUsername(), textOrCin);
        }

        else if (option == "cancel" || option == "Cancel") {
            break;
        }
    } while (option != "cancel" || option != "Cancel");
}
```

Debug output:

```
Successfully logged in...


Main Menu:
[0] Order Plan
[1] Generate Plan
[2] Manage Profile
[3] Manage Exhibits
[4] Manage Animals
[5] Manage Users
[6] Search Animal/Exhibit by Name
[7] Record Favorability
[8] Log Animal/Exhibit Care
[9] Add or Remove an Exhibit
[10] Add or Remove an Animal
[Cancel] To exit

Please input number of selected option: 0
]ption: [0
option.size(): [2]
```

I should only be pulling in "0", but as seen in 'option.size(): [2]' there is something extra that is messing it up.

Even when it is just an empty line in the text file it will pull that weird scrambler character in (size should be 0 but is 1 and still scrambles).

My only thought is that I am using a weird new line character in my .txt file that g++ doesn't recognize. (.txt was made in sublime text editor).

I have tried copying my code and text files into notepad saving it, closing, re-opening, and pasting into emacs, but still not luck.

Note: All functionality works with manaul input with VS, and G++.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1:
I have outputted option to a text file and got the weird character, it is "^M".

Answer (score -1):

Solved: It was exactly what I said. My test document used windows newline characters, not Unix.

Fix: Use an online converter to convert your .txt file from Windows supported characters to Unix character supported characters.

Edit #2: I used http://newline.nadav.org/

Note: I am in no way affiliated with the website I shared above!

Comment: `getline()` reads until `\n` is reached. On Windows, it also handles `\r\n` for you.  On *Nix, if `getline()` doesn't automatically handle `\r\n`, it is a simple matter to check if the output ends with `\r` and strip it off before processing the output.